# How to get only nested data in Laravel collection

Tags: collections, laravel-8

I wrote a database selection like this (Laravel 8):

```
$users = collect(User::with(['roles','roles.permissions'])->find(21));
```

The result is the following

```
=> Illuminate\Support\Collection {#2051
     all: [
       "id" => 21,
       "first_name" => "test",
       "name" => "test",
       "..." => "...",
       "roles" => [
         [
           "id" => 9,
           "name" => "Test",
           "permissions" => [
             [
               "id" => 13,
               "name" => "userReadList",
             ],
             [
               "id" => 11,
               "name" => "userUpdate",
             ],
           ],
         ],
         [
           "id" => 4,
           "name" => "responsible",
           "permissions" => [
             [
               "id" => 10,
               "name" => "userRead",
             ],
             [
               "id" => 9,
               "name" => "userCreate",
             ],
           ],
         ],
       ],
     ],
   }
```

Now: What I have to change in the query to get only an array, containing the permissions id as follow: `[13,11,10,9]`?

Or is my query principal wrong for getting the permissions id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
$userPermissions = collect(User::with(['roles','roles.permissions'])->find(21));

Arr::flatten(Arr::pluck($userPermissions['roles'] , 'permissions.*.id'));

//[13,11,1,4,]
```

But I think, the better way is the following

```
$userPermissions = User::with(['roles','roles.permissions'])->find(21);

$userPermissions->roles->pluck('permissions.*.id')->flatten()->toArray();

//[13,11,1,4,]
```

Also possible it the following approach

```
$userPermissions = User::with(['roles','roles.permissions'])->where('id',21)->get();

$userPermissions->pluck('roles.*.permissions.*.id')->flatten()->toArray();

//[13,11,1,4,]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{
"Roshan ": [
{
"2023-05-27": {
"check_in": "2023-05-27 09:03:00",
"check_out": "2023-05-27 10:18:00",
"is_manual": 1,
"remarks": "f",
"user_name": "Roshan ",
"date": "2023-05-27"
},
"2023-05-26": {
"check_in": "2023-05-26 05:00:00",
"check_out": "2023-05-26 04:14:00",
"is_manual": 1,
"remarks": "f",
"user_name": "Roshan ",
"date": "2023-05-26"
}
}
],
"RR": [
{
"2023-05-26": {
"check_in": "2023-05-26 21:16:00",
"check_out": "2023-05-26 18:18:00",
"is_manual": 1,
"remarks": "r",
"user_name": "RR",
"date": "2023-05-26"
}
}
]
}......How to get nested data from the date
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).